# Can someone help with this sentence involving double denial? 無いこともないのですが

Tags: meaning, negation

> 実は全く手段が無いこともないのですが、それがあなたのためになるとは俺には到底思えません

Can someone explain 無いこともないのですが? It's a double denial from what I can tell. So does it become this:

> Actually it's not like there's no method at all, however I cannot possibly think that it will be useful to you

Comment: That's correct. It's a double denial and your translation is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup!

The double negatives cancel to make it affirmative.  It does show the writers hesitation in telling the listener about them or to use the method at all.

手段が無いことないですが --> 手段がある